# Need to transfer a header via groovy or properties file in REST which is retrieved via service?

Tags: rest, soapui

I'm new in REST and tried to search for how do I transfer my header which I get via service to other service via code or properties file.
Please help

Comment: need to transfer an element which is retrieved from a service as header to other service.

Comment: Would you please care to provide the raw response and what value you need to extract?

Answer (score -1):

You can use Filter to get the header. Below is the example:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;

public class ExtensionContainerRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {


    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext reqCtx) throws IOException {

         MultivaluedMap<String, String> headers = reqCtx.getHeaders();
        //TODO continue with your logic 
    }

}
```